# Divide numpy array Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have this piece of code:

```
n = np.load(matrix)["arr_0"]
shape = n.shape
##colsums and rowsums
rows = {}
cols = {}
for i in xrange(shape[0]): #row
    rows[i] = np.sum(n[i,:])
for j in xrange(shape[1]): #cols
    cols[j] = np.sum(n[:,j])
##looping over bins
for i in xrange(shape[0]): #row
    print i
    for j in xrange(shape[1]): #column
        if rows[i] == 0 or cols[j] == 0:
            continue
        n[i,j] = n[i,j]/math.sqrt(rows[i]*cols[j])
```

It basically loops over a numpy matrix with shape `(50000,50000)` and I need to divide each value for the square root of the product of the sum of the corresponding column by the sum of the corresponding row. My implementation takes ages. Do you have any suggestions to improve its performance?

Comment: There is usually no need for explicitly using loops when using `np.array`. If you are then you are probably over-complicating something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply take the sums individually on each axis, then take the outer product, then the square root. This can be condensed a bit but it gives you an idea how to vectorize it.

```
# Sum of rows and columns
a = numpy.sum(data, axis=1)
b = numpy.sum(data, axis=0)

# Product of sum and columns
c = numpy.outer(a,b)

# The square root...
d = numpy.sqrt(c)

# ...a nd the division
data /= d
```

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'h') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

Comment: There is a type difference between `data` and `d`, you can just do `data  = data/d` instead, or find/fix the type difference.

Comment: I think that it throws the error since I have rows and columns which sum is 0. So, invalid division.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner solution using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.where((rows[:,None]==0) | (cols==0),n,n/np.sqrt((rows[:,None]*cols)))
```